# Infinite scroll for Angular 13.3.10

Tags: angular, infinite-scroll

I can't seem to find any infinite scroll libraries for Angular 13.3.10. Could someone please explain how I may make an infinite scroll that loads components rather than images?

I tried using ngx-infinite-scrol

Comment: You mean components with media in them like cards or tiles etc?

Comment: Exactly, it;s an Angular card component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Angular Material SDK](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview).
You could render a list and pass the `item` prop as input to a custom component to render that item.

```html
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50" class="example-viewport">
  <div *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items" class="example-item">
    <custom-component [item]="item"></custom-component>
   </div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```